# How to change sharepoint site defaultzone

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server

how to change sharepoint site defaultzone
In default zone url is: http://site1.com
i want to change http://site1.com to Intranet zone and in default zone i want to extend webapplication with https certificate

i require:

> default zone url: https://site1.com
>
> Intranet zone : http://site1.com

for this

1. can i delete default zone site this site on port 80?
2. can i extend webapplication port 443 on default zone after i remove defaul zone site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are couple of ways to do it, I would do this way

- Edit the public URL of the web application ( central admin > application management > configure AAM...here select the web application and then click edit public urls), update it with https url
- update the IIS with SSL cert
- Now add the new URL in AAM and put it in intranet zone.

here is another approach discussed here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2013/02/27/how-to-properly-change-the-host-header-url-of-a-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: after i update AAM in default zone can i restart sharepoint foundation web application service running in wfe servers?

Comment: also can i extend the webapplication to port 443 ?

Comment: You dont need to reset IIS after changing the AAM...You can extend the web application for port 443...but i would simply update the IIS bindings with port 443 and SSL cert.